# in razor add the URL param to a div

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have razor form like so

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

     <div id="email_label" style="font-size:14px;padding:8px;">Email:</div>
     <div class="form-group">
         @Html.EditorFor(x => x.user, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "enter email from url" } })<br />
         @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.user)
      </div>
}
```

I want to replace the `placeholder = "enter email from url"` with the value from the url.

url: `example.com/login?email=hi@example.com&pass=123`

Right now i am doing this in Javascript but i would want to do this in Razor. But i cant seem to get anywhere.

Here is what i am doing in Javascript:

```
let url = new URL(window.location.href);
let searchParams = new URLSearchParams(url.search);
let emailAddress = (searchParams.get('email'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the query string from `Request` and use it

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.user, 
                  new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", 
                              placeholder = Request["email"] ?? "Please enter email" } })
```

This will read the email query string value if it exist as the place holder value, else the string "please enter email"

This will only add the place holder text,not the actual value of the input. If you want this to be set as the input element value, you can do that in your GET action method.

```
public ActionResult ResetPassword(string email)
{
   var vm = new ResetPasswordVm { User  = email };
   return View(vm);
}
```

and the helper method will use this value when rendering the input